# What is the benefit to add W3C logo in site?

Tags: html, css, w3c, semantic-markup, w3c-validation

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/Icons

- If my code is valid then Should i add
  logo to all my personal and client
  sites.?
- Should i add logo to client sites and
  tell to client these are good to
  have?
- If code is valid but semantically
  correct even can we use logo?
- What is benefit and purpose to add
  these logos for XHTML, CSS
  accessibility.
- And what is the difference between
  **Gold** and **Blue** logo
- Why W3C provide these logos?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417123/what-is-the-point-of-using-w3c-valid-badges

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's completely useless in my opinion - it wastes bandwidth, it serves no real purpose. The only people who really use it are the ones who just found about w3 validator usually, and they stop using it after awhile. The ones who do leave it on their sites usually don't even bother fixing validation errors after a couple years and you click on the icon and you see that the site has X # of errors.

> And what is the difference between
>   Gold and Blue logo

One is blue, the other is gold. The reference doesn't state any difference so I would assume it's just color.

> Why W3C provide these logos?

For novice developers to have bragging rights and put something on their page.

Answer (score 2):

Those logos are just for 'pride'. they don't give you any benefit.
Is just to let your visitors know that your html/xhtml/css is valid.

Answer (score 1):

wether your site is css + xhtml valid or not it will run in the customers browser that counts.

only webdesigner know about these logos any visitor of your site is not interested in this information its superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I have the W3C valid logos on certain areas of my site (that are to do with my work professionally and the 'geeky' areas) to show that I have taken into consideration some aspects of good web practice.

There's nothing wrong with a little self promotion IMHO :-)

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I. to give to them a backlink from your site
II. to allow them to store cookies

please note! there is no such thing as free lunch. you have to pay some way.